# How do I clip a floating-point number to just below a limit?

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, clipping

Functions like [`numpy.random.uniform()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html) return floating point values between a two bounds, including the first bound but *excluding* the top one. That is, `numpy.random.uniform(0,1)` may yield 0 but will never result in 1.

I'm taking such numbers and processing them with a function that sometimes returns results outside of the range. I can use [`numpy.clip()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html) to chop values outside of the range back to 0-1, but unfortunately that limit is *inclusive* of the top number.

How do I specify "the number infinitesimally smaller than 1" in python?

Comment: If math is to be believed, you can't.

Comment: in most systems there is a concept of epsilon, which is the smallest increment

Comment: Uh-oh, I can sense a `0.99999... < 1` flame war brewing

Comment: I don't think I'm in paradox (or flame-war) land with this. Or are you saying that `numpy.random.uniform(0,1)` will actually sometimes return a number equal to 1? If that's the case, then, okay, fine. I don't really care about the paradox, but I want my modified-then-clipped numbers to be guaranteed to be in the same range that the originals are.

Comment: I think wim is referring to the idea that the real number 0.9999... (repeating) is actually exactly 1 in mathematics. Floating point numbers are not real numbers, so it's not especially relevant to your question. However, I will take this opportunity to note the cases when `uniform(x,y)` might (extremely rarely!) give you results equal to `y`. It shouldn't happen with `uniform(0,1)`, but in other cases, the floating point arithmetic used to rescale the underlying `[0,1)` random number to your bounds might sometimes give `y` exactly.

Comment: Thanks @RobertKern. I noticed that the Python `random` docs say that; the numpy docs should probably be updated include that disclaimer as well.

Comment: Person who downvoted — any suggestion as to why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, if you're using numpy, you can simply use [numpy.nextafter](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.coremath.html):

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.nextafter(1, 0)
0.99999999999999989
```

Note that (at least for me):

```
>>> import sys
>>> 1-sys.float_info.epsilon
0.9999999999999998
>>> numpy.nextafter(1, 0) - (1-sys.float_info.epsilon)
1.1102230246251565e-16
>>> numpy.nextafter(1, 0) > (1-sys.float_info.epsilon)
True
```

Incidentally, to second @Robert Kern's point that sometimes random.uniform *will* include the upper bound for some inputs other than (0, 1):

```
>>> import random, numpy
>>> numpy.nextafter(0,1)
4.9406564584124654e-324
>>> random.uniform(0, numpy.nextafter(0,1))
0.0
>>> random.uniform(0, numpy.nextafter(0,1))
0.0
>>> random.uniform(0, numpy.nextafter(0,1))
4.9406564584124654e-324
```

[I share the general sense that there is probably a better way to approach this problem.]

Comment: why isn't it the case that `numpy.nextafter(1, 0) == (1-sys.float_info.epsilon)`, is it because the density of floats changes depending on magnitude?

Comment: @wim: yep.  1+epsilon/2 = 1, but 1-eps/2 = nextafter(1,0).

Answer (score 3):

Python's [sys](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html) provides an `float_info` struct with an  `epsilon` attribute and is defined as

> difference between 1 and the least value greater than 1 that is representable as a float

So I would suppose something like

```
def clip(num):
    if(num >= 1):
        return 1 - sys.float_info.epsilon
    return num
```

should do the trick. Although this is generally bad, and there are probably tons of reasons why you should never attempt this.

**EDIT** I just observed one such reason - implementation. While CPython does what you'd expect, my first go-to choice is IronPython, which [doesn't](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/workitem/27840) (although it's a bug). Ye be warned!

Comment: So... is there a not-generally-bad approach?

Comment: It really depends on why you need your function to be in [0, 1). Do you want to ignore values >= 1? Do you want to include those values as 1 - eps? Who's taking those values, and why does that guy need them to be [0, 1)? You state that there exists a library function u that returns [0, 1). Then you f(u()) these numbers and return [0, inf), but want to return [0, 1) ...why? Presumably there's an h(f(u)), and  maybe we should focus on the h. :)

Answer (score 2):

In most practical cases you don't need to be infinitesimally smaller, you can approximate it. So for your example I'd use 0.9999999 instead of 1.0.