# Drawing floating numbers with [0, 1] from uniform distribution by using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, uniform

I'm currently trying to draw floating numbers from a uniform distribution.

The Numpy provides numpy.random.uniform.

```
import numpy as np
sample = np.random.uniform (0, 1, size = (N,) + (2,) + (2,) * K)
```

However, this module generates values over the half-open interval [0, 1).

How can I draw floating numbers with [0, 1] from a uniform distribution?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the use case where this makes a difference?

Answer (score 11):

It doesn't matter if you're drawing the uniformly distributed numbers from (0,1) or [0,1] or [0,1) or (0,1]. Because the probability of getting 0 or 1 is zero.

Comment: +1 even though for a computer algorithm, the probability of getting the end point is not strictly zero.

Comment: I would also simply ignore it. For the highly improbably event that 1 is sampled, rejecting it is a possibility, but likely too expensive to be worthwhile.

Answer (score 4):

[random_integers](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.random_integers.html#numpy.random.random_integers) generates integers on a closed interval. So, if you can recast the actual problem of yours into using integers, you're all set. Otherwise, you may consider if granularity of 1./MAX_INT is sufficient to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

From the standard Python [random.uniform documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.uniform) :

> The end-point value b may or may not be included in the range depending on floating-point rounding in the equation a + (b-a) * random().

So basically, the inclusion of the end point is strictly based on the floating-point rounding scheme used. Therefore, to include 1.0, you need to define the precision required by your operation and round the random number accordingly. If you do not have a defined precision for your problem, you can use [numpy.nextafter](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.coremath.html#npy_nextafter). Its usage was covered by a previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9406985/873106).

Comment: as a nitpick: it's usually a bad idea to mix `random`s from the standard library and from `numpy`.

Answer (score 0):

If your software depends on the difference between `[0,1)` and `[0,1]` then you should probably roll your own random number generator, possibly [the one mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720822/best-pseudo-random-number-generator) in order to ensure that it meets these stringent requirements.